# In C, why do preferred RDBMS' drivers implement different API, instead of a uniform API?

Tags: c, rdbms, libpq, mysql-connector-c

In Java, mostly different RDBMS' drivers implement JDBC API.

In Python, mostly different RDBMS' drivers implement DB-API2.

In C, although we have ODBC as uniform API for different RDBMS', people in general prefer RDBMS-specific API, such as those provided by [libpq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145000/odbc-v-libpq-c-library-for-postgresql), and [C connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679244/c-application-libmysqlclient-versus-odbc) (I am not sure about sqlite3 vs its ODBC counterpart). Why do the preferred RDBMS' drivers implement different API, instead of a uniform API in C? Is there some inherent difficulty to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: I feel like this question would fit better on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Just a flat out guess which is why I'm not putting this as an answer, but a solution specific to one RDBMS would allow for optimizations specific to that system. A general solution may not allow for these optimizations as they may not work for all RDBMSs thus being potentially slower (though maybe not slow to the point where it becomes an issue).

Comment: There's an [XKCD about this exact thing](https://xkcd.com/927/). A lot of this boils down to ecosystem concerns and history. You build on what already exists, carry forward with the inertia you have.

Comment: @GovindParmar when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 4):

Languages like Java and Python provide a higher level abstraction layer over databases so that a generic interface can be used and the underlying database can be changed out if need be.  This flexibility comes at a cost of vendor-specific functionality not being exposed.

The C APIs provided by each vendor allow the use of functionality specific to each database.  This means vendor lock-in but it also allows you to exploit these vendor specific features and perform vendor specific optimizations.

The Java and Python runtimes most likely use the underlying C APIs internally.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the vendor-specific parts of API. But for vendor-agnostic parts of API, which I guess are also the most commonly used parts, they can still be designed uniformly over RDBMS', correct? For example, psycopg2 adheres to DB-API2, but still have postgresql specific parts. Can't the drivers in C also be made like that?